# Value not printing out

Tags: c++, derived-class

I am trying to print this function which is using a derived function.

```
void Dairy::print(void){
    cout << setw(20) << right << whoAmI() << setw(15) << right << this->getFat()<< setw(15) << right << this->getDatePurchased.getDay()<< setw(15) << right << this->getExpireDate().getDate() << setw(15) << right << this->getCholesterol() << endl;
}
```

The error says the reference to the nonstatic member must be called.
What could the error be?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the rest of the class definition.

Comment: Maybe there's bugs in the code we can't see? Please show enough we can at least reproduce the problem. Always include the *full* error.

Comment: At a guess, `this->getDatePurchased.getDay()` -> `this->getDatePurchased().getDay()`.  And you don't need `this->`.

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.